# I want to know how to use Github in open source

Tags: github, github-pages

I am a programming starter to try github for the first time.

https://github.com/froala/design-blocks

I completed the clone as described in the main link.
I have also completed the npm installation as described in the text and have successfully run it.
But if i simply want to use source code, do i not need to install the module using npm?
Why do I install the module using npm?..

How do I use the packages I installed using npm?

Even if I did a search on Google, there was no post for beginners like me.

I really appreciate your advice.

Comment: Try googling for "Froala Tutorial"

Comment: Note that there's no single way to use things you find on GitHub. They're not all built using some "GitHub methodology". Any time you're trying to find out how to use a particular thing you find, read its readme, visit its website, look for tutorials and sample code, etc.

Comment: Are you trying to use GitHub, or are you trying to use that particular software project which happens to be *hosted* on GitHub?  They are two very different things.

Comment: Thank you all for your commit. There is no formal use.   
I will read the readme file hard. Thank you very much.